# InvalidOperationException with service_timer

Tags: c#, sql, service, timer, invalidoperationexception

I'm developing a windows service in C# and it accesses the database several times when files are dropped into a specific directory.   Furthermore, I have a service_timer that runs every 5 minutes that also accesses the database.  The issue then, is that when my service is processing a file and my service_timer is called, I end up getting an InvalidOperationError (There is already an open Data Reader).

Is there a way to create a new connection for to the database (on Microsoft SQL Server Express) so I can avoid this problem, or is there another common solution?

Thanks.

Here is the code of the function where the exception is being thrown:

```
            DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

            string SqlQuery = "SELECT COUNT (*) AS recCount FROM " + tableName + " " + whereclause;

            Debug.WriteLine(thisMethod + " SqlQuery: " + SqlQuery);
            myCommand = new SqlCommand(SqlQuery, this.SDB); //Execute Sql Statement

            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            // Create New Adapter

            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);


            adapter.SelectCommand = myCommand;

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            // Populate Adapter

            adapter.Fill(ds);

            foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    recCount = Convert.ToInt32(dr["recCount"]);
                }
```

Comment: Yes, by all means create a new, local db connection in the timer callback.

Comment: Well I am creating a new SQLConnection each time already.

Comment: Please show the relevant code with an indication where you get the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies here

```
myCommand = new SqlCommand(SqlQuery, this.SDB);
```

You should create a new SQLConnection within the method instead of using a global.

```
SqlConnection newConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
newConn.Open();
myCommand = new SqlCommand(SqlQuery, newConn);
//Rest of logic
newConn.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks!  I will try that tomorrow and let you know how it works

Comment: I'm getting this exception now: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'USERNAME'.  It wil still properly connect with the DB calls in the main service.

Comment: Are you using the same connection string as in your other method?

Comment: ...no, if it connected the first time it should connect the second time, ensure you are using the exact connection string you used in the other method that is successful.

Comment: The problem seems to have gone away with a bit more testing but I am afraid it will come back.  Should I mark your answer as the answer and create a new thread if it reoccurs, or leave this question open?

Comment: The original problem or the new exception?  The new exception should probably be a new question as I don't think it's related to the information you've provided here.